# Why some of the apache server functions are declared with APU_DECLARE()?

Tags: apache

I look into the source code of apache server, some of the function is declared as below:

```
APU_DECLARE(const char *) apr_xml_empty_elem(apr_pool_t *p,const apr_xml_elem *elem);
```

APU_DECLARE is a definition declared as follow:

```
#define APU_DECLARE(type)   type
```

I do not understand why it does like this. APU_DECLARE seems useless. Does it have special meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `#define APU_DECLARE(type)            __declspec(dllimport) type __stdcall` for WIN32.

It allows them to be cross platform.